# CompareObjectHandles(HANDLE, HANDLE) Windows function

Tags: c++, windows, handle

When I try to use the function `CompareObjectHandles` it gives `LNK2019` Unresolved external symbol `__imp_CompareObjectHandles`
I want to use it to compare device handles. I can't use the `GetFileInformationByHandle` because it works only on files.

I have already added `#pragma comment(lib, "kernel32.lib")` in my code and it is also declared in `#include <handleapi.h>`.

Comment: this api not exist in kernel32.lib ( simply search this string in lib and you view). it exist in *onecore.lib* (*mincore.lib* , *mmos.lib* ) - the *Kernelbase.lib* not exist in public sdk/wdk

Comment: Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-compareobjecthandles). Include `<windows.h>` link with `Kernelbase.lib`

Comment: I now added #pragma comment(lib, "kernelbase.lib") to my code and it gives different error "LNK1104 cannot open file 'kernelbase.lib'"

Comment: but are you read ? - *Kernelbase.lib* **not exist** in public sdk/wdk